MatTable - Prevent recreation of columns
I have a filter component inside the header of each column of my mat-table, if filtering is enabled for this column. The component has UI and logic to configure and apply filters of different types (number, text, date, selection).
The problem is, that the filter is reset (the filter component is re-rendered) when I hide/show a dynamic column (for example for buttons) although the rest stays the same. This loses all filter data. I also can't save the filter data outside of the filter component, because I can differentiate between removing the component because filtering was disabled or re-rendering. Both times ngOnDestroy is called. So I don't know when to keep the data and reapply it and when to delete it.
Is there a way to prevent recreation of columns that are present before and after hiding/showing a dynamic column:
I created a minimal reproducible example. In this I don't want the counter in the column header to increase after the first time.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vwxz6d

When any component is under a "*ngIf" condition, when condition becomes false it's destroyed, when condition becomes true the variables are initialized and execute the "ngOnInit".
The typical is not use *ngIf="condition" else [style.display]="!condition?'none':null" -see that in style.display we use the opposite of condition.
When we have a mat-table the "*ngIf" are when we change the displayColumns
We can use some like:[style.display]="dynamicColumns.indexOf(column)<0?'none':null" to have like
allPossible:string[]=['buttonColumns'] //<--here all
dynamicColumns:string[]=[]

<ng-container *ngFor="let column of allPossible" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th [style.display]="dynamicColumns.indexOf(column)<0?'none':null" 
             mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
    <td [style.display]="dynamicColumns.indexOf(column)<0?'none':null" 
             mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button *ngIf="column === 'buttonColumn'" mat-button>Action</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

And always displayColumns are the "meta"+"dynamicColumns"

Hmm okay. But I don't see where the *ngIf is. The one in the button column can be removed and the problem still occurs. In the implementation of the mat-table there could be an *ngIf for each column but since the static columns are present before and after toggling, the condition of showing the column stays the same, so it should not be re-rendered. At least thats what I would expect. The button column is obviously re-rendered and thats fine

@MarcelLorenz, When I say "*ngIf" it's not a real *ngIf it's only a way to indicate "when a column is created/eliminate". In mat-table is change the displayColumns variable. My answer is related to not change de "displayColumns" else change the "style.display" of the th/td of the column.

Thanks I understand your approach and will implement it but still I don't get why the columns are re-rendered since the data did not change, the templates did not change only the displayColumns changed but contains the same names/keys (for static columns). Like I said I would expect the table to keep the th/td of the static columns and only add/remove the ones that changed.
